# Alternet raw color in StringGrid in C++ Builder XE

Tags: colors, tstringgrid, c++builder-xe

I want to use string grid in my C++ Builder XE Program in two alternate color of white & sky blue.
I want to make odd raw white & even raw sky blue so please tell me how can i do it.

Please help me to do so in C++ Builder XE

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `OnDrawCell` event to draw all of the cells yourself manually.  You can then assign whatever colors you want to the grid's `Canvas` while drawing.